# Fullscreen Window On Primary Screen

Tags: c#, wpf

#### The Problem

I have an application where the main-window needs to be maximized on the primary screen, right from the beginning. But as soon as i start the application from another screen, it will go to fullscreen on this particular screen and not the primary.

#### Question

What do i have to do, to accomplish the desired behavior?

Comment: Google "wpf wm_getminmaxinfo" to find code.

Comment: It's about forcing the window to maximize on the primary screen only, not about reading the screen metrics via the Win32 API. Witch there is actually a solution implemented in .NET, see System.Windows.Forms.Screen

Comment: It is about forcing the MINMAXINFO.ptMaxPosition value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Solution

1. Add these flowing References to your Solution: ([How to: Add and Remove References (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx))

   - [System.Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)
   - [System.Windows.Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx)
2. Set your [Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx).[WindowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx) to [WindowState.Normal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate.aspx)

   (C#)

   ```
   Window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
   ```

   (XAML)

   ```
   WindowState="Normal"
   ```
3. Delegate a [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742550.aspx) to the [Window.Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) Event

   (C#)

   ```
   Window.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click));
   ```

   (XAML)

   ```
   Loaded="Window_Loaded"
   ```
4. Add the EventHandler method

   ```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left;
       this.Top  = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top;
       this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
   }
   ```

#### Explanation

Basically we grab the Location from top-left corner of the primary screen and assign it's values to our window. After that we let the window switch to maximized, that does what it says on the box. Maximizing the window, this time always on the primary screen.

#### References

- [FrameworkElement.Loaded Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx)
- [How to: Handle a Routed Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742550.aspx)
- [RoutedEvent Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedevent.aspx)
- [How to: Add and Remove References in Visual Studio (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [System.Drawing Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)
- [System.Windows.Forms Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx)
- [Window Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx)
- [Window.WindowState Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx)
- [WindowState Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
ScreenObject = Screen.AllScreens; 
yourForm.Top = ScreenObject[1].Bounds.Height;
yourForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
yourForm.Location=newPoint(ScreenObject[1].Bounds.Location.X,
ScreenObject[1].Bounds.Location.Y);
yourForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Is `ScreenObject[1]` always the primary?

Comment: no, it is the secondary screen on my example. the idea there is you can specify on what screen your display form gonna show up . sorry for my English :)

Comment: Ok, basically you've proposed the same solution, as i did. Except for some minor details. And minus the explanation.